# Excel [Standard Deviation] of range filtered against another range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Firstly - no VBA if it can be helped please!

I am trying to get the Standard Deviation of a range of cells, filtered against a second range (where I want to list specific exclusions.

I have the data in a table with columns of `Batch No`, `Date`, `Weight` and can easily filter for a range of dates with:

```
=STDEV.S(IF(Table1[Date]>=Start_Date,IF(Table1[Date]<=End_Date,Table1[Weight])))
```

(Entered as an array formula) I can also filter out a specific Batch Number like:

```
=STDEV.S(IF(Table1[Date]>=Start_Date,IF(Table1[Date]<=End_Date,IF(Table1[Batch No]<>7097,Table1[Weight]))))
```

What I would like to do is have a list of more than one `Batch No` to exclude, adding to this list as needed.  I have tried to do this by listing the exclusions in a range and having a cell as an array of this range, then using this cell as the filter, e.g. `C2 =7097`, `C3 =7085`, `D3 {=C2:C3}` and pointing the above formula to `D3` instead of just `7097` but no luck.

Any help gratefully received please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Match:

```
=STDEV.S(IF(Table1[Date]>=Start_Date,IF(Table1[Date]<=End_Date,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Table1[Batch No],$C$2:$C$3,0)),Table1[Weight]))))
```

Depending on one's version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Thanks @Scott - A really elegant solution and one I never would have got to myself!